# Problem installing packages

Tags: linux, r, installation

I am installing Matrix on a Linux x86_64 multicore system. I receive a message:

```
Warning message:
In install.packages("Matrix", dependencies = TRUE) :
  package 'Matrix' is not available
```

Sure enough, there are not many details on package troubleshooting. It appears that Matrix is available for x86_64, but it's not available in any repository. How come?

Comment: Can you add any better tags please?

Comment: Suggestions welcome. It seems just an R environment issue, and couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: Works fine here.  I have the following in my .Rprofile: r <- getOption("repos");
r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.us.r-project.org";
options(repos = r);
rm(r)

install.packages("Matrix", dependencies = TRUE) ran and installed everything cleanly.  Note also that the Matrix package should be included in recent R versions.

Comment: Leo, do you do this with su privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you do this (and ti doesn't require `su` or `sudo`):

```
R> repos <- "http://cran.r-project.org"
R> AP <- available.packages(contrib.url(repos))
R> AP[ which(AP[,1]=="Matrix"), 1:3]
      Package       Version      Priority 
     "Matrix" "0.999375-38" "recommended" 
R>
```

The only time I ran into issue similar to the one you are reporting was when my R version was out of sync with how the repo is organized (ie too old).

Comment: Dirk, the problem seems to be solved. I repeated the same commands today, and Matrix installed with 0 status. For some reason, Matrix was not available on a number of repositories I tried. My server was never rebooted. In fact, I never exited the R session.
Having said that, I was worried that there would be some conflict between (old) packages I installed via apt-get from Ubuntu repositories, and (new) packages I was trying to install via install.packages(). Since you port/maintain debian packages, could there be any problem there?

Comment: No, there is no problem related to your upgrade as the .deb package installs in another directory than the direct install. There are some other issues to consider related to 'mixing' which got mentioned in other SO questions, as well as on r-sig-debian.